# How to Capture Approval Comments in Case Object Custom field called comments ? Below code i am getting an error trigger depth exceeded?

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

```
trigger CaseApprover1 on Case (after update) {
    List<ProcessInstance> instances = [SELECT Id,TargetObjectId,(SELECT Id, StepStatus, Comments FROM Steps) 
                                       FROM ProcessInstance Where ProcessDefinitionId =:'04a7F000000HMpZQAW'];
    system.debug('===>'+instances);
    Set<String> objectIds = new Set<String>();
    for(ProcessInstance pi:instances){
        objectIds.add(pi.TargetobjectId);
    }
    Map<Id,Case> csemap = new Map<Id,Case>([Select Comments__c from Case Where Id in:objectIds ]);
    system.debug('=====>'+csemap);
    for(ProcessInstance pi:instances){
        for (ProcessInstanceStep step : pi.Steps) {
            if(step.StepStatus == 'Approved') {
                csemap.get(pi.TargetObjectId).Comments__c = step.Comments;
            }
            else if(step.StepStatus == 'Rejected'){
                csemap.get(pi.TargetObjectId).Comments__c = step.Comments;
            }
        }
    }
    update csemap.values();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are updating `Case` in `update csemap.values();` which is again trigging the `CaseApprover1`  trigger.

And in the trigger `Case` is getting updated again.

This becomes endless.

You need to implement a mechanism to break this endless process.

You can you a static variable as a flag which can be set and you should check value for the same before calling `update csemap.values();`.

And another way

You can achieve this functionality by creating trigger for ProcessInstance and update the `Case` object there.